# Limit on set of rational points implies is zero limit on set of real points is zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ converging uniformly.Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(p,q)=0$, for all rational numbers $p,q$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$

I think the problem is proved using triangle inequality and the fact that every real number can be approximated by a rational number, i.e. dense nature of reals. Is it right. Moreover, any counterexamples in case of non-uniform convergence?Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Perhaps use the fact that if f and g are continuous on some arbitrary metric space X, then the set $\{x \in X: f(x)=g(x) \}$ is closed? Since $\Bbb{Q}^2$ is dense in R2.

Comment: @LiChunMin so you mean to say that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(p,q)=f=0$ on a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which should be closed , i.e., must contain its limit points?

Comment: I think so. $$$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most important fact to solve your first question is that the uniform limit of continuous functions is again continuous. Indeed set $f := \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n$. Take any $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$, and take $\{x_n, y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathbb{Q}^2$ which converge to $(x, y)$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have
$$ f(x, y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n, y_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} f_m(x_n, y_n) = 0.$$
Note that what I am doing is essentially exchange of limits. So $f = 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If you drop the assumption that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly, then things are a bit different. For instance lef $f_n$ be a continuous function which is $1$ on $\{ (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}) \}$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ if $|x - (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})| \geq \frac{1}{n}$. Then the limit $f$ is $1$ on $\{ (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}) \}$ and $0$ elsewhere. So $f$ is not identically zero.

What I feel interesting is that although limit of continuous functions is not necessarily continuous, the limit function cannnot be extremely chaotic. For instance one cannot obtain a function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is 1  on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ elsewhre as a limit of continuous functions. This is a consequence of Baire's category theorem, which is a bit difficult topic here. To prove this, here we assume the following fact, which can be derived with some trick from Baire's category theorem;

**FACT:** $\mathbb{Q}$ cannnot be represented as an intersection of countable open sets.

By way of contradition suppose that we have a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which converge to a characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$. Set $V_N := \cup_{n=N}^{\infty} \{x \in \mathbb{R} | f_n(x) < 1/2 \} \,\,\,(N \in \mathbb{N})$. Then each $V_N$ is open. Furthermore $\mathbb{Q} = \cap_{N \in \mathbb{N}} V_N$. In fact take $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. As $f_n(x) \to 0$, for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find $n \geq N$ for which $f_n(x) < 1/2$. Thus $x \in \cap_{N \in \mathbb{N}} V_N$, implying $\mathbb{Q} \subset \cap_{N \in \mathbb{N}} V_N$. By a similar resoning we can say that if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, $x \notin\cap_{N \in \mathbb{N}} V_N$ . Therefore  $\mathbb{Q} = \cap_{N \in \mathbb{N}} V_N$. This contradicts the above fact, since each $V_N$ is open.

Comment: great answer! by the way, I understand Baire-Category theorem: no complete set can be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets. how does that help here?

Comment: The above fact is actually famous and probably can be found in many textbook that deals with Baire's theorem. For instance you can refer to Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, Theorem 5.13.